# Why does doxygen always reprocess every file?

Tags: c++, optimization, build, doxygen

When a project is built, only the files that changed after the last build are recompiled. Is it possible to get a similar behavior in doxygen?

Now it seems that doxygen always makes a clean/rebuild of its generated files whenever it is run.

With big projects such an optimization would save a lot of time.

Comment: So don't run it until you're done with your code changes. I don't see how introducing the complexity of dependency resolution in _rendered documentation_ could possibly be worthwhile.

Comment: Does anyone read the doxygened documentation?  If not, only generate it when the code is released.

Comment: @cup: If no-one reads it, why generate it _at all_?

Comment: @cup: doxygen documentation is pretty useful during development, too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good point - some archaic sites require documentation to be generated regardless of whether anyone reads it.  The techies don't need it, management want it because it ticks their boxes.  It is complaints galore when people do read it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the techies do need it, because most of them are sorely lacking mind-reading abilities.

Comment: So, in order to let at least one useful comment in this stack : did you find a way to do this since this post ? I'm running exactly in the same problem and the Doxygen process takes ages, its is quite problematic.

Comment: @Benj - I do not think much has changed under this point of view, unfortunately.

Comment: @Pietro sadly it seems to be the situation

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, doxygen is a one-shot program: it reads some source files and writes some html files.

To be able to work like C/C++, it would need to have separate "compilation" (parse the source and write possible incoming and outgoing references to an "object" file) and "link" (read "object" files and resolve all references) steps. Implementing that is left as an exercise :)

And then you'd have to worry about source vs. header files... It's more hassle that it's worth so nobody implemented it.

Comment: Well, a compiler and a linker which should be flexible enough for this purpose are already available: [LLVM](http://llvm.org).